# Proving $\forall f\in \mathbb R ^{\mathbb R}(f\neq i_{\mathbb R})\to (\exists g\in \mathbb R ^{\mathbb R} (f\circ g \neq g\circ f))$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, predicate-logic

> Prove $\forall f\in \mathbb R ^{\mathbb R}(f\neq i_{\mathbb R})\to (\exists g\in \mathbb R ^{\mathbb R} (f\circ g \neq g\circ f))$

Proof by contradiction:

For all $f(x)\neq x$ and $(\forall g\in \mathbb R ^{\mathbb R} (f\circ g = g\circ f))$

Let $f\in \mathbb R ^{\mathbb R}$ such that $f(x)\neq x$ and since the statement is for all $g$ then we can take: $g(x)=5$.

Compose the two functions:

$f(g(x))=f(5)=m, s.t: m\neq 5 \\
g(f(x))=g(a)=5, s.t: a\neq x$

So we have $5=m$ but $m\neq 5 $. contradiction.

Is the $f$ I used general enough?

Comment: If $i_\mathbb{R}$ denotes the identity function on $\mathbb{R}$, then $f \neq i_\mathbb{R}$ does not mean that $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}.\ f(x) \neq x$ (which you use), but rather that $\exists x\in \mathbb{R}.\ f(x) \neq x$.

Comment: If $f\neq i_x$, then $\exists a\in\Bbb{R}$ s.t. $f(a)\neq a$. Let $g$ be the constant function $g(x)=a$, then $$f(g(a))=f(a)\neq a=g(f(a)).$$

Comment: @dtldarek ah, well if I'll change my $g$ to be that $x$, i.e. $g(x)=k: \exists k\in \mathbb R: f(k)\neq k$ then it would ok I assume.

Comment: @kuhaku Indeed.